# How to upgrade PostgreSQL 9.6 to 10 in Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu, upgrade

Is there any simple apt-get version?

Some people here said the long process was OK for them.
 (https://gist.github.com/delameko/bd3aa2a54a15c50c723f0eef8f583a44)

Comment: Install new binaries, run `pg_upgrade` or use `pg_dump` and `pg_restore`

Answer (score 4):

> Is there any simple apt-get version?

Yes. As described in the webpage you linked to, you can install PostgreSQL 10 using the official posgres apt repository (instead of the default Ubuntu repository for 16.04):

```
sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/ xenial-pgdg main"
wget --quiet -O - https://www.postgresql.org/media/keys/ACCC4CF8.asc | sudo apt-key add -
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install postgresql
```

You can remove the old version (9.6) *beforehand*, e.g. by

```
sudo apt-get remove postgresql-* pgadmin3* pgagent
```

But make sure you backup your database first so that you can restore it after the upgrade as pointed out in the comments.

Comment: I would be careful, there are some caveats.  First, before you remove the Pg-9.6, you'll need to dump and load into Pg-10. Second, while PostgreSQL is awesome for bundling it for Ubuntu, it's not bundled by Ubuntu: this means it likely wont work with the core administration utilities of the OS https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/189512/2639 You'll have to administer it with the pg toolchain and if you're running other versions managed by Ubuntu that sounds like no fun. For an example of the problems you're likely to encounter see [this question](https://askubuntu.com/q/965016/29097) on [ubuntu.se]

Comment: @EvanCarrollQWERHJKL I agree with what you said in the other question. Maybe there are more sophisticated use cases that I missed. I didn't run into any issues upgrading to pg10 as above because I only use pg_{dump, restore}, {create,drop}db etc. And I only keep one version in my Ubuntu to avoid the complexities.

Comment: What happens if I don't remove the 9.6 bits? Will they remain on the system forever but be unused? Why will the database be gone when I remove the application package? Can I also remove 9.6 after installing 10? That doesn't look like an upgrade strategy.

Comment: @ygoe `Can I also remove 9.6 after installing 10? That doesn't look like an upgrade strategy` I remove 9.6 *before* adding the new repo and installing 10 because it will remove the latest version (9.6) from the default Ubuntu repo. I'm not sure what happens if you remove the old version after installing a new version, or whether a different order/route would work.

Comment: @tinlyx Oh I've already got 9.6 from the pgsql repo because my Ubuntu only had something older. So I'm switching from the vendor's 9.6 to 10.

Comment: _sudo apt-get remove postgresql-*_ is inadequate, as the shell will expand  `postgresql-*` based on the files that match in the current directory, if there happens to be.